# how to get text from textview

Tags: android, textview

if I have set text in textview in such way, which is not problem:

```
  tv.setText("" + ANS[i]);
```

this simply getting from this way.

```
     String a = tv.getText().toString();
     int A = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

But in case of setting value in textView.

```
 tv1.setText("  " + X[i] + "\n" + "+" + " " + Y[i]);
```

which is like this

```
              5
             +9
```

I have problem , this value how to get.

Comment: Do you want to show the result of addition of those numbers..?

Comment: my question is, I have 5+9 value in one textview as i already mention., so how to get this value like tv.getText().toString();

Comment: Does not tv.getText().toString() work?

Comment: @jave he needs to convert it to int so he dont want only number not any other chars.

Comment: Right, I updated my answer with how to get a list of all the numbers and not just the sum.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I haven't tested this - but it should give you a general idea of the direction you need to take.

For this to work, I'm going to assume a few things about the text of the `TextView`:

1. The `TextView` consists of lines delimited with `"\n"`.
2. The first line will not include an operator (+, -, * or /).
3. After the first line there can be a variable number of lines in the `TextView` which will all include **one** operator and **one** number.
4. An operator will allways be the first `Char` of a line.

First we get the text:

```
String input = tv1.getText().toString();
```

Then we split it up for each line:

```
String[] lines = input.split( "\n" );
```

Now we need to calculate the total value:

```
int total = Integer.parseInt( lines[0].trim() ); //We know this is a number.

for( int i = 1; i < lines.length(); i++ ) {
   total = calculate( lines[i].trim(), total );
}
```

The method calculate should look like this, assuming that we know the first `Char` of a line is the operator:

```
private int calculate( String input, int total ) {
   switch( input.charAt( 0 ) )
      case '+':
         return total + Integer.parseInt( input.substring( 1, input.length() );
      case '-':
         return total - Integer.parseInt( input.substring( 1, input.length() );             
      case '*':
         return total * Integer.parseInt( input.substring( 1, input.length() );             
      case '/':
         return total / Integer.parseInt( input.substring( 1, input.length() );
}
```

---

**EDIT**

So the above as stated in the comment below does "left-to-right" calculation, ignoring the normal order ( + and / before + and -).

The following does the calculation the right way:

```
String input = tv1.getText().toString();
input = input.replace( "\n", "" );
input = input.replace( " ", "" );
int total = getValue( input );
```

The method `getValue` is a recursive method and it should look like this:

```
private int getValue( String line ) {
  int value = 0;

  if( line.contains( "+" ) ) {
    String[] lines = line.split( "\\+" );
    value += getValue( lines[0] );

    for( int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++ )
      value += getValue( lines[i] );

    return value;
  }

  if( line.contains( "-" ) ) {
    String[] lines = line.split( "\\-" );
    value += getValue( lines[0] );

    for( int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++ )
      value -= getValue( lines[i] );

    return value;
  }

  if( line.contains( "*" ) ) {
    String[] lines = line.split( "\\*" );
    value += getValue( lines[0] );

    for( int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++ )
      value *= getValue( lines[i] );

    return value;
  }

  if( line.contains( "/" ) ) {
    String[] lines = line.split( "\\/" );
    value += getValue( lines[0] );

    for( int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++ )
      value /= getValue( lines[i] );

    return value;
  }

  return Integer.parseInt( line );
}
```

Special cases that the recursive method does not handle:

- If the first number is negative e.g. -3+5*8.
- Double operators e.g. 3*-6 or 5/-4.

Also the fact the we're using `Integers` might give some "odd" results in some cases as e.g. 5/3 = 1.

Comment: This won't work very well. Consider the following scenario: 5 + 5 * 3
The actual result is 20 (5 + 5 * 3 = 5 + 15 = 20), but your code strictly operates from left to right ignoring the fact that multiplication/division should be treated first and gives 30 (5 + 5 * 3 = 10 * 3 = 30).

Comment: Which is why I stated: "but it should give you a general idea of the direction you need to take.".

Comment: Yeah, just pointing it out so someone doesn't get confused when it isn't working as they expected (as you stated you hadn't tested it).

Answer (score 3):

split with the + sign like this way

```
String a = tv.getText().toString();
String aa[];
if(a.contains("+"))
    aa = a.split("+");
```

now convert the array

```
Integer.parseInt(aa[0]); // and so on
```

Comment: String a tv.getText().toString(); , this is i dont understand.

Comment: you have to replace "\n" with the "" and then trim the string after that split the string

Answer (score 3):

it is me code if you like get your Text View Content to String

```
    TextView TextViewTest = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    String Test1 = TextViewTest.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this,Test1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this.

```
tv1.setText("  " + Integer.toString(X[i]) + "\n" + "+" + " " + Integer.toString(Y[i]));
```

Comment: he want value from textview not set into the textview he already set the value into the textview

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following:

```
a=a.replace("\n"," ");
a=a.trim();
String b[]=a.split("+");
int k=Integer.ValueOf(b[0]);
int l=Integer.ValueOf(b[1]);
int sum=k+l;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is the sum of all the numbers you want, I made a little snippet for you that can handle both + and - using a regex (I left some print-calls in there to help visualise what happens):

```
    final String string = "  " + 5 + "\n" + "-" + " " + 9+"\n"+"+"+" "+5; //Or get the value from a TextView
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(-?).?(\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    System.out.print(string);
    System.out.print('\n');
    int sum = 0;

    while( matcher.find() ){
        System.out.print(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.print(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.print('\n');
        sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)+matcher.group(2));
    }
    System.out.print("\nSum: "+sum);
```

This code prints the following:

```
  5
- 9
+ 5
5
-9
5

Sum: 1
```

Edit: sorry if I misunderstood your question, it was a little bit unclear what you wanted to do. I assumed you wanted to get the sum of the numbers as an integer rather than a string.

Edit2: to get the numbers separate from each other, do something like this instead:

```
    final String string = "  " + 5 + "\n" + "-" + " " + 9+"\n"+"+"+" "+5; //Or get the value from a TextView
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(-?).?(\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while( matcher.find() ){
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)+matcher.group(2)));
    }
```