# hide button if text length is < 1 in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity, findviewbyid

I'm new to Android and Java and I'm busy editing an existing app. I am trying to hide a button if no text is getting pulled in from a webservice. I have made it work with another button when the text is being populated

```
if (textEvent.length() > 1) {
    buttonEventSetup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

but when I used:

```
if (textEvent.length() < 1) {
    buttonAccessControl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

nothing seems to happen.

I don't know if the code snippet is in the wrong place or something else is overwriting the code. Here is my activity code:

```
package com.example.dsouchon.myapplication;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button buttonEventSetup =    (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonEventSetup);

    if(Local.isSet(getApplicationContext(), "LoggedIn"))
    {
        String loggedInUser = Local.Get(getApplicationContext(), "LoggedIn");
        if(loggedInUser.length()>0)
        {
            buttonEventSetup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            buttonEventSetup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        buttonEventSetup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if(Local.isSet(getApplicationContext(), "EventName"))
    {
        String event =  Local.Get(getApplicationContext(), "EventName");
        TextView textEvent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textEventName);
        textEvent.setText( event);
        Button buttonAccessControl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAccessControl);
        buttonAccessControl.setEnabled(true);

        //HIDES SET EVENT BUTTON WHEN EVENT IS SET
        if (textEvent.length() > 1) {
            buttonEventSetup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if (textEvent.length() < 1) {
            buttonAccessControl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Button buttonAccessControl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAccessControl);
        buttonAccessControl.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if(Local.isSet(getApplicationContext(), "EventImage"))
    {
        TextView textEvent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textEventName);
        String result =  Local.Get(getApplicationContext(), "EventImage");

        ImageView imageViewEventImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewEventImage);
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(result, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        imageViewEventImage.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void setupEvent(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupEvent.class );
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void accessControl(View view) {
    Button buttonEventSetup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonEventSetup);
    buttonEventSetup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity21.class );
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void Logoff(View view) {
    Local.Set(getApplicationContext(), "LoggedIn", "");
}

public void Login(View view) {
    final AlertDialog ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    MySOAPCallActivity cs = new MySOAPCallActivity();
    try {
        EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUserName);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        String user = userName.getText().toString();
        String pwd = password.getText().toString();
        LoginParams params = new LoginParams(cs, user, pwd);

        Local.Set(getApplicationContext(), "UserName", user);
        Local.Set(getApplicationContext(), "Password", pwd);

        new CallSoapLogin().execute(params);
       // new CallSoapGetCurrentEvents().execute(params);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ad.setTitle("Error!");
        ad.setMessage(ex.toString());
    }
    ad.show();
}

public class CallSoapLogin extends AsyncTask<LoginParams, Void, String> {

    private Exception exception;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(LoginParams... params) {
        return params[0].foo.Login(params[0].username, params[0].password);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO: check this.exception
        // TODO: do something with the feed
        try {

        TextView loginResult =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.labelLoginResult);
        loginResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loginResult.setText(result);

       // Button buttonUnsetEvent = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUnsetEvent);
       // buttonUnsetEvent.setEnabled(true);

        //Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        //spinner2.setEnabled(true);

        boolean LoginSuccessful = false;

        if(result.toLowerCase().contains("success"))
        {
            LoginSuccessful = true;
        }

        if (LoginSuccessful)
        {
            String user = Local.Get(getApplicationContext(), "UserName");
            Local.Set(getApplicationContext(), "LoggedIn", user);
            LinearLayout layoutLoggedIn = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutLoggedIn);
            layoutLoggedIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Button buttonEventSetup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonEventSetup);
            buttonEventSetup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            LinearLayout layoutLogIn = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutLogIn);
            layoutLogIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           String e3 = ex.toString();
        }
    }
}
private static class LoginParams {
    MySOAPCallActivity foo;
    String username;
    String password;

    LoginParams(MySOAPCallActivity foo, String username, String        password) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

       }
     }
}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging to check if the code you use for hiding the button is reached?

Comment: textEvent is a textView, not a String, `textEvent.getText().toString();` otherwise you will get any way a size for it cuz its returning an iD unless its null

Comment: oh textevent is a textview, didn't notice! @Charuka is right, that is the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get text from textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517730/how-to-get-text-from-textview)

Comment: so how would i fix that. Sorry. im a newbie

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the length of Textview that will not work.Use the text length.This should work

```
   String event =  Local.Get(getApplicationContext(), "EventName");
    //HIDES SET EVENT BUTTON WHEN EVENT IS SET
    if (event.length() > 1) {
        buttonEventSetup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (event.length() < 1) {
        buttonAccessControl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code above `textEvent` is not a string value. It is an Object of type `TextView`. `length()` in this case will not return the length of the text contained within that element. You will need to explicitly get the text string before you can get the length of it. This is acquired using the `getText()` method on the `TextView`.

Your code should look like the following:

```
//HIDES SET EVENT BUTTON WHEN EVENT IS SET
        if (textEvent.getText().length() >= 1) {
            buttonEventSetup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (textEvent.getText().length() < 1) {
            buttonAccessControl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

You also have `INVISIBLE` on both cases in your posted code example.

Note that your code also does not handle cases where the text length == 1. You could simplify the whole block with the following.

**Note:** any value != 0 is classed as true

```
buttonEventSetup.setVisibility(textEvent.getText().length() ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
```