# Change action of a button according to text displayed

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, textview, android-button

I would like to know how to change the action of a button according to what text is display in a TextView. I am using Android Studio.

I have tried to use an 'if statement' but that doesn't seem to work. So, I want a different sound to play according yo what text is displayed in the TextView.

```
package com.msp.exampleapplication;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PrimaryClass extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView placeholder;
    Button playsound_button;
    MediaPlayer mySound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.primary_layout);

        placeholder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
        playsound_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playsound_button);

        placeholder.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("message"));

        }

    public void playSound(View view) {

        if (placeholder.equals("BMW M4")) {

            mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
            mySound.start();
        }

        else if (placeholder.equals("BMW M5")) {

            mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
            mySound.start();
        }
    }
}
```

So, if the text of the TextView (placeholder) is "BMW M4", then when the button is clicked, it must play R.raw.sound. And if "BMW M5" is displayed in the TextView (placeholder), then R.id.sound2 must play.

But as I said, I've attempted to use the if statement and when I click the button, no sound plays at all.

Comment: Your if statement checking is wrong, do it like `if (placeholder.getText().toString.equals("BMW M4"))`

Comment: When I do that, 'toString' becomes red and say's, "cannot resolve symbol 'toString'"?

Comment: @MSP , toString is a function not an attribute - that's just a small mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as @Akshay Bhat 'AB'  said, you must do this:

```
   if (placeholder.getText().toString().equals("BMW M4")) {

        mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
        mySound.start();
    }

    else if (placeholder.getText().toString().equals("BMW M5")) {

        mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
        mySound.start();

    }
```

Refer this post: [how to get text from textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517730/how-to-get-text-from-textview)
There's one error in the comment tho, its `toString()`  and not `toString`

Comment: Thank you so much! It all works now, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to **[check the text in the TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText())** and not the reference of the TextView itself.

```
   placeholder.getText().toString().equals("BMW M4")
```